# Anomalous Green's function

Tags: arrows, feynmf, feynman

Is it possible to draw a line (or double line) with two out-out or into-into arrows in `feynmf`? Such (anomalous) diagrams appear, e.g. in perturbation theory of Bose condensates.

Following http://einrichtungen.ph.tum.de/T30e/HEP/computing/feynmf/Teil3.html I tried this code

```
\begin{fmffile}{anomal}
\fmfcmd{%
style_def anomal1 expr p = cdraw p;
cfill (harrow (reverse p, .5));
cfill (harrow (p, .5))
enddef;
style_def anomal2 expr p = draw_double p;
cfill (tarrow (reverse p, .55));
cfill (tarrow (p, .55))
enddef;}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(100,60)
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{anomal1}{i1,o1}
\fmf{anomal2}{v1,o2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
```

but it doesn't work. This is a kind of a picture I have in mind [image]. I've successfully done similar thing previously, but stil can't drow a out-out or into-into line.

Comment: Please draw a picture of the desired output.

Comment: ...and show what you've tried by giving a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) for the best approximation that you already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use phantom and dbl_plain_arrow. Here is an example:

```
    \documentclass[class=minimal,border=20pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{feynmp}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{fmffile}{diagram}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(250,250)
        \fmfleft{i}
        \fmfright{o}
        \fmf{phantom}{i,m,v,h,o}
        \fmffreeze
        \fmf{fermion,label=$~$}{i,v}
        \fmf{dbl_plain_arrow,label=$~$}{h,v}
        \fmf{dbl_plain_arrow,label=$~$}{h,o}
        \fmfv{d.sh=circle,d.f=30,d.si=.1w}{v}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
    \end{fmffile}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using the strange hard code for my opinion of `feyn` package you can obtain the equation of your picture drawing with your hand.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{feyn}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{split}
\feyn{ms mA} & = \feyn{fA +  fc ms mA} {\mkern-70mu \scriptstyle\Sigma}\\
& + \feyn{fc ms mV mA} {\mkern-108mu \scriptstyle\Sigma'} 
\end{split}\]
\[
\begin{split}
\feyn{mV mA} & = \feyn{fVc mA} {\mkern-55mu \scriptstyle\Sigma''}\\
& + \feyn{fVc mV mA } {\mkern-90mu \scriptstyle\Sigma'} 
\end{split}
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the following

```
\begin{fmffile}{Dyson Beliaev}
\vspace{3em}

\fmfcmd{%
style_def anomal_in_out expr p =
draw_double p;
cfill (tarrow  (p, .1));
cfill (tarrow  (p, .6))
enddef;
style_def anomal_in_in expr p =
draw_double p;
cfill (tarrow (reverse p, .65));
cfill (tarrow (p, .65)) 
enddef;
style_def anomal_out_out expr p =
draw_double p;
cfill (harrow (reverse p, .45));
cfill (harrow (p, .45)) 
enddef;}


\begin{fmfgraph*}(40,40)
\fmfstraight
\fmfleft{l1}
\fmfright{r1}
\fmf{anomal_in_out}{l1,r1}
\fmfv{label=$=$,label.dist=60,label.angle=0}{r1}
\end{fmfgraph*}
%%%%
\hspace{3em}
%%%%
\begin{fmfgraph*}(40,40)
\fmfstraight
\fmfleft{l1}
\fmfright{r1}
\fmf{fermion}{l1,r1}
\fmfv{label=$+$,label.dist=60,label.angle=0}{r1}
\end{fmfgraph*}
%%%%
\hspace{3em}
%%%%
\begin{fmfgraph*}(90,40)
\fmfstraight
\fmfleft{l1}
\fmfright{r1}
\fmf{fermion}{l1,v1}
\fmf{anomal_in_out}{v1,r1}
\fmffreeze
\fmfv{d.sh=circle,d.f=empty,l=$ \Sigma_{11}$, d.size=9mm, l.dist=0, l.angle=180}{v1}
\fmfv{label=$+$,label.dist=60,label.angle=0}{r1}
\end{fmfgraph*}
%%%%
\hspace{3em}
%%%%
\begin{fmfgraph*}(90,40)
\fmfstraight
\fmfleft{l1}
\fmfright{r1}
\fmf{fermion}{l1,v1}
\fmf{anomal_in_in}{v1,r1}
\fmffreeze
\fmfv{d.sh=circle,d.f=empty,l=$ \Sigma_{21}$, d.size=9mm, l.dist=0, l.angle=180}{v1}

\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
![Dyson Belieav eq](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUYnm.jpg)
```